# C++ set iterator after the next delimiter recursiv?

Tags: c++, string, iteration, delimiter

Problem: it_begin iterator should be placed behind the next deli

I need a solution where "s" is not touched only it_begin steps though the String to the next

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

string s("foo $deli: baa $deli: don't $deli: matter")
string deli("$deli:");

string::const_iterator it_begin = s.begin();
string::const_iterator it_end   = s.end();

// calculate

// while(it_begin at the last deli )
{



  cout << string(it_begin, it_end) << endl;     
}
```

Output 1 " baa $deli: don't $deli: matter"

Output 2 " don't $deli: matter"

Output 3 " matter"
...

Comment: Use std::string::find and more effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work (untested):

```
std::string::const_iterator it_begin = s.begin();
std::string::const_iterator it_end = s.end();
std::string del = "$deli";

while ( (it_begin = std::search(it_begin, it_end, del.begin(), del.end()))
         != it_end ) {
    it_begin += del.size();
    std::cout << std::string( it_begin, it_end );
}
```

This calls `std::search` repeatedly until there's no delimiter left to be found in the string. Note the increment of the resulting iterator - this is to avoid infinite loop.

EDIT: [Tested live example.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6dd137640b816869)

Comment: std::search() is no standart methode ! where did you get it?

Comment: In <algorithm> header. Yes it's standard.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution work proper! The live example is a realy usefull tool. I never know it befor.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use iterators. You can use member function `find` of class `std::string`

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main();
{
    std::string s("foo $deli: baa $deli: don't $deli: matter");
    std::string deli("$deli:");

    typedef std::string::size_type size_type;

    for ( size_type i = 0; ( i = s.find( deli, i ) ) != std::string::npos; i += deli.size() )
    {
        std::cout << s.substr( i + deli.size() ) << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The iterator is used on the string for other things, too. That is the reason i need it. I search for a function like this: it_begin = std::search(it_begin, it_end, del.begin(), del.end()) but in std there is no one

Comment: @Tun Zarni Kyaw You alwasy can get the iterator using begin() + i